# Converting 5 volts to 12 volts using a photocoupler

Tags: opto-isolator, level-shifting

i have an arduino and i need to convert 5 volts to 12 volts in order to trigger a 12 volt Rele, i am considering to use the circuit that i attached here (below), if the "input" square is 5 volts, what is the square "output" voltage according to the image below, how is the math calculus of voltages of this circuit taking into account that +12 source voltage is applied at the final part (above 4.7k ohms), thank you very much, anyhelp is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need galvanic isolation? I would normally just do this with a low-side FET switch.

Comment: do you have the diagram of the circuito that you describe?, thank you very much for your help

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html

Comment: The output will be a 12V pulse - provided that the impedance of your load - ground is large; otherwise the output forms a potential divider. Look up potential dividers for the maths you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram doesn't show any of the part specs, but consider the transistor as a perfect on-off switch.  If it is open circuit, then the output terminal is simply connected to the +12 through the 4.7Kohm resistor, and can source 12V/4700ohm=2.5mA of current.  When the transistor is closed, it will sink the 2.5mA and whatever else it is capable of.

If your relay needs more than 2.5mA, you could need a smaller pullup, but you don't want to overload the transistor's capacity.  If you need more than the optoisolator can handle, add a transistor or mosfet to the output.

Comment: Yes, but what is the squared "output" voltage according to the image?,

Comment: is it less than 12 volts?

Comment: If there is no load on the output it is 12V.

Comment: If is there a load, the voltaje at the output will reduce a lot?

Comment: It depends on the load.  Measure the ohms of the coil of your relay, if it is 10000 ohms, then the voltage will drop to 12*10000/(10000+4700) = 8V  If it is 100 ohms, then it will drop to 12*100/(100+4700) = 0.25V.

Comment: the relay needs 12 volts to switch (work normally), the relay coil is 232 ohms, do the relay work 12*232/(232+4700)=2784/(4932)=0.5644 :(, I will reduce 4700 ohms to 1 ohm :)

Comment: 1 ohm may overload your optoisolator's transistor with 12A when it is on.   You need to supply 12V at 12V/232ohms= 50mA, so you need to do use this to drive a transistor like www.instructables.com/id/Connecting-a-12V-Relay-to-Arduino

Comment: Thank you, i measured the resistance exactly as www.instructables.com/id/Connecting-a-12V-Relay-to-Arduino i will use a resistance in order not to overload the optoisolator's transistor

Comment: Instead of this circuit what circuit do you recommend in order to convert 5 volts to 12 volts??

Comment: The relay should be connected in place of the 4K7 resistor, and will be on when the input is low.  However, you should check the cvurrent capability of the Opto's transistor - if the relay needs more current than the opto's transistor can handle, you may need to add a higher-current transistor to drive the relay.